# 21.10 - Unable to write to Samba share without SU in Ubuntu. Windows can write using the exact same Samba credentials

Tags: permissions, samba

Relatively new to Ubuntu. 21.10. Stuff I've tried so far:

I have seen other threads regarding this and have made sure the Samba share names and folder names do not match. Folder actual name: `nasdrive` | Share: `4tb` | Mount point: `nas`

Mounted via fstab. Using credentials stored in a local file, `~/.smbcreds`, which is called in fstab.

Windows can read/write without any issues whatsoever, when using the exact same samba credentials.

Ubuntu can write to the share ONLY from console via `sudo touch /media/nas/testfile`

fstab entry: `//192.168.50.56/NASdrive /media/nas cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/username/.smbcreds`

The .smbcreds file is as follows:

`USERNAME=user`

`PASSWORD=P@s5w0rd`

The Samba share is hosted from a Raspberry Pi. It's a physically separate machine from the computer attempting to write.

Comment: Is the Samba share on the same Ubuntu machine or hosted elsewhere? Can you [edit] your question to include the `fstab` line?

Comment: Hey @matigo - made the requested updates. Thanks for checking this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIFS will mount a share with owner = root and permissions of 755 so only root will be able to write to the share on the client.

One way to fix this is to replace root with you so you become the owner. You do that by adding `uid=username` ( where username is your local login user name ) to the list of options.

Change this:

```
//192.168.50.56/NASdrive /media/nas cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/username/.smbcreds
```

To this:

```
//192.168.50.56/NASdrive /media/nas cifs uid=username,vers=3.0,credentials=/home/username/.smbcreds
```

Comment: Brilliant. This did the trick. Thanks for sharing your expertise!! I'd vote you up but you apparently need 15 rep to do that and I have no idea how to acquire it.

Comment: This worked for me as well, The weird part that I tried to edit using sudo some of the file contents it did not work. Never expected this was the solution !